# Stray @ in program with NSDictionary definition

Tags: objective-c, ios

In the course of following a howto online, I came across the following code:

```
NSDictionary *address = @{
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey: _address.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey: _city.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey: _state.text,
  (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey: _zip.text
};
```

Which will not compile in XCode 4.5.1. I get two errors:

1. Stray '@' in program
2. Expected '}' before ':' token

What am I missing here? Also, where do I find documentation on this shortcut declaration of an NSDictionary object? It's awfully hard to Google syntax like this.

Comment: What iOS version are you compiling this in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is part of [Obj-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html), introduced since LLVM 4.0. Make sure you are using the right version of iOS as well. Translated into original pre-llvm 4.0 language, the NSDictionary assignment would look like this:

```
NSDictionary *address = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey, _address.text, 
                        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressCityKey, _city.text,  
                        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressStateKey, _state.text, 
                        (NSString *)kABPersonAddressZIPKey, _zip.text, 
                        nil];
```

Comment: Solved. I was using a slightly older version of Xcode (on Snow Leopard). I'm not sure what version it was exactly, but upgrading to Lion caused Xcode to prompt me to upgrade LLVM and a few other components, and this syntax now works. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's a part of modern objective c, and it's called objective c litterals.
This code should works well, maybe you are using and old compiler, make sure that you are using the last compiler (currently LLVM 4.1)

Answer (score 3):

The @ declaration is an Objective-C literal.  Link to info:

[Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)